# Comment out a value from PHP file via bash?

Tags: linux, bash, scripting, sed

So, I'm working on a bash script and in a function I need for it to comment out two values in a PHP file.

```
define('WP_CACHE', true); //Added by WP-Cache Manager
define( 'WPCACHEHOME', '/home/fescobar/public_html/testground/wp-content/plugins/wp-super-cache/' ); //Added by WP-Cache Manager
```

I managed to get rid of the first line using the following.

```
first="define('WP_CACHE', true);"; sed "s/$one/testingwp/g" wp-config.php
```

However, that method fails on the second. My main objective here is just to comment out both lines with //* in front of those values. but, I always get a sed syntax error.

Comment: That method should fail on the first as well.  What's the value of `$one`?

Comment: @WilliamPursell made an error, on the post. first should be one.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you just want:

`sed '/WP_CACHE/s|^|//|'` and `sed '/WPCACHE/s|^|//|'`

This will prepend `//` to an line that contains the string `WP_CACHE` or `WPCACHE`.  If you are trying to restring the replacements to lines that also match `^define`, try:

`sed '/^define(.WP_CACHE/s|^|//|'`  (you can actually match the quote character, but using `.` is easier to type.  You need to refine the question more to describe what you are trying to do.

Comment: I'm just trying to comment out or possible remove.
define('WP_CACHE', true); //Added by WP-Cache Manager
define( 'WPCACHEHOME', '/home/fescobar/public_html/testground/wp-content/plugins/wp-super-cache/' ); //Added by WP-Cache Manager

I tried your examples but it made no change whatsoever.

Comment: If the first two examples I gave did not add `//` to the beginning of any line that contains the text `WP_CACHE` or `WPCACHE` then you probably entered the command incorrectly. (That or your implementation of `sed` is broken, or you are expecting it to change the file instead of working as a filter.)